# ikec causes high cpu usage when started as background process

Tags: vpn, cpu-load, mint

When using the CLI for the shrewsoft vpn client, ikec, as a background process, it causes 100% cpu usage.

I start following bashscript

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                
ikec -r confFile -u User -p Password -a > /dev/null 2>&1 &
echo "Waiting for 5 sec..."
sleep 5
sudo mount -a
```

This causes 100% cpu usage by ikec, because it is started as a background process. This doesn't happen when not starting it as a bg process or using qikea.

Anyone knows what causes this and how to fix it?

I'm using Linux Mint 18.1.
Ike package version is 2.2.1+dfsg-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same Problem.

As u mentioned the high CPU usage only appears when running ikec in background.

My solution for this is using GNU Screen.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y screen

sudo screen -S "ikecl1702" -d -m ikec -r l1702 -u user -p password -a
```

This will run ikec in the background with a pseudo tty